# GridSearchCV generates different best parameters by only changing the order of param_grid setting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am using GridSearchCV to find the best parameter setting of my sklearn.pipeline estimator. The pipeline consists of data transformation, UMAP dimension reduction and Kmeans clustering.
The final Kmeans clustering results are scored using silhouette_score. I tried to verify the whole pipeline/GridSearchCV worked correctly by only changing the parameter order in param_grid (
e.g., change 'reduce__n_neighbors': (5, 10), to 'reduce__n_neighbors': (10, 5)). I got totally different best parameters although I expect the parameter order change should not impact the
best paramters determined by GridSearchCV.

Below is the code. The Debug class is used to save the output from 'reduce' step. This saved output is used in cv_silhouette_scorer() to calculate silhouette_score. I suspect Debug class and cv_silhouette_scorer() did not work as I expected.

Thank you very much for your help.

```py
class Debug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.transX = None

    def transform(self, X):
        print(X)
        self.transX = X.copy()
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

def cv_silhouette_scorer(estimator, X):
#     estimator.fit(X)
    sdata = estimator.named_steps['debug'].transX
    cluster_labels = estimator.named_steps['cluster'].labels_
    num_labels = len(set(cluster_labels))
    num_samples = sdata.shape[0]
    if num_labels == 1 or num_labels == num_samples:
        return -1
    else:
        return silhouette_score(sdata, cluster_labels)


ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary', dtype=np.float32)
ore = OrdinalEncoder(dtype=np.float32)
ctenc = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('ohe', ohe, nom_vars), ('ore', ore, ord_vars)], 
                          remainder='passthrough')
nftr = FunctionTransformer(nominal_indicator_missing, check_inverse=False, 
                          kw_args={'feat_names': ohecols, 'orig_cols': nom_vars})
oftr = FunctionTransformer(ordinal_indicator_missing, check_inverse=False,
                            kw_args={'miss_value': 0.})

ctmiss = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('nftr', nftr, slice(0, 19)), ('oftr', oftr, slice(19, 20)), ('drop_cols', 'drop' , slice(32, 36) )], remainder='passthrough')

mputer = IterativeImputer(random_state=RS, add_indicator=True, initial_strategy="most_frequent", skip_complete=True)


# Add below keep_vars transformer to drop all demographic columns before pass to UMAP

keep_cols = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('keep_cols1', 'passthrough' , slice(17, 25) ), ('keep_cols2', 'passthrough' , slice(46, 54) )] )

scaler = StandardScaler()

trans = FunctionTransformer(np.transpose, check_inverse=False)

dreduce = umap.UMAP(random_state=RS)
knn = KMeans(random_state=RS)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('enc', ctenc)
        , ('functr', ctmiss)
        , ('mpute', mputer)
        , ('keep_cols', keep_cols)
        , ('scale', scaler)
        , ('trans', trans)
        , ('reduce', dreduce)
        , ("debug", Debug())
        , ('cluster', knn)
    ]
)

parameters = {
    'mpute__max_iter': (15, 20),
    'reduce__n_neighbors': (5, 10),
    'reduce__min_dist': (0.02, 0.05),
    'reduce__n_components': (2, 3),
    'reduce__metric': ('euclidean', 'manhattan'),
    'cluster__n_clusters': (2, 3),
    'cluster__n_init': (10, 25)
}
# parameters = {
#     'mpute__max_iter': (20, 15),
#     'reduce__n_neighbors': (10, 5),
#     'reduce__min_dist': (0.05, 0.02),
#     'reduce__n_components': (3, 2),
#     'reduce__metric': ('manhattan', 'eucidean'),
#     'cluster__n_clusters': (3, 2),
#     'cluster__n_init': (25, 10)
# }

def cv_silhouette_scorer(estimator, X):
#     estimator.fit(X)
    sdata = estimator.named_steps['debug'].transX
    cluster_labels = estimator.named_steps['cluster'].labels_
    num_labels = len(set(cluster_labels))
    num_samples = sdata.shape[0]
    if num_labels == 1 or num_labels == num_samples:
        return -1
    else:
        return silhouette_score(sdata, cluster_labels)

gsearch3 = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, n_jobs=-1, scoring=cv_silhouette_scorer , cv=5, verbose=1)
gsearch3.fit(dfnew)
```